# Clean FPDF & FPDI Installation on a laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, fpdf, fpdi

I tried several things to install FPDF and FPDI on my laravel project but it just doesn't work and it's never clear.

Can you guys explain to me how i can do so ?

Comment: Please let us know what you followed and whats the error you are getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [codedge/laravel-fpdf](https://github.com/codedge/laravel-fpdf) package?

Install it through Composer:

```
composer require codedge/laravel-fpdf
```

Publish the config file and edit it as needed:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Codedge\Fpdf\FpdfServiceProvider" --tag=config
```

Add package's service provider and alias to your `config/app.php` file:

```
return [
    //...

    'providers' => [
        // ...
        Codedge\Fpdf\FpdfServiceProvider::class,
    ],

    // ...

    'aliases' => [
         // ...
        'Fpdf' => Codedge\Fpdf\Facades\Fpdf::class,
    ]
]
```

Test it:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    Fpdf::AddPage();
    Fpdf::SetFont('Courier', 'B', 18);
    Fpdf::Cell(50, 25, 'Hello World!');
    Fpdf::Output();
});
```

Hit your app root in browser and see if it generates a PDF file as expected.

Comment: This doesn't include FPDI, does it? I would like to read existing PDF and modify it and I can't find a way to do it with this package.